# BASH error on tests [[ ]]

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to be able to validate that something is in the form of an IP in a bash script and I found various pieces of code online... they all have about the same structure..

```
#!/bin/bash


valid_ip()
{

    local  ip=$1
    echo $ip

    if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        ret=0 # is an IP
    else
        ret=1 # isn't an IP
    fi

    return $ret

}


# SCRIPT -------------------------------------

#clear the table
ipfw table 1 flush

ips=$(dig -f ./hostnames.txt +short)


# For each of the IPs check that it is a valid IP address
# then check that it does not exist in the ips file already
# if both checks pass append the IP to the file
for ip in $ips
do
    if valid_ip $ip; then 
        if grep -R "$ip" "~/Dropbox/ProxyBox Stuff/dummynet/ips.txt"; then 
                echo "$ip already exists"
            else
                echo $ip >> ips.txt

        fi
    fi

done


# get the IP's and add them to table 1
cat ips.txt | while read line; do
ipfw table 1 add $line
done
```

Anyway I am getting the following error

```
./script.sh: 18: ./script.sh: [[: not found
```

I can't understand why I can't complete this test... any help would be appreciated.

I call the script with

```
sudo ./script.sh
```

I believe using sudo is contributing to the problem, but I need sudo pfor other parts of my script.

Comment: hmm, the snippet you have provided works for me. Are you sure this is the line 18 that the error comes from?

Comment: How do you call the scipt?

Comment: Interestingly it works when I just type it in the console, but not in my script..... line 18 is the if [[ .... ]] in my code ....

bash -version: GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).....

call script: sudo ./script.sh

Comment: @user2041602: Is the first line really `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @user2041602 what is the value of $ip?

Comment: @choroba yes. I'll update the original post with my entire script, perhaps that would help.

Comment: @Kent it is any particular IP address or hostname.

Comment: I believe @choroba is onto something with how I am calling the script.... I think using sudo is a problem for that line, but the ipfw commands need sudo so I cannot run the script without it.

Comment: interesting.. have you tried `sudo bash script.sh` already? just checking

Comment: @user2041602 what is the output of `which bash`? usually this message happens when your shell doesn't support `[[...]]` test.

Comment: @zzk that appears to solve the problem... I'm not sure why? ... Kent which bash outputs /bin/bash

Comment: Then it is a little bit weird. [[ is only recognized by a limited number of shells (this is your primary problem, as your shell does not appear to recognize [[ and is looking for a command of that name. This is surprising if your shebang does indeed specify /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh)

Comment: @user2041602 not sure why.. from your comments the bash is `/bin/bash`, then the script should have worked with `./script.sh`.. there is something fishy preventing it from using the bash

Comment: Hm. well, I guess I should thank you all for helping me get through this situation. I'm just glad it works now despite its odd behaviour. If someone could clarify for me how to mark this question as closed/solved that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `[[ ... ]]` test is in all versions of BASH since the first release (the `[[ ... ]]` is taken from Kornshell), it is possible that there may be some Bourne shell compatibility setting in your version of BASH. However, the only thing I could turn up is compiling BASH without the `--enable-cond-command`. Try typing this:

```
$ /bin/bash -c help
```

This will print out a bunch of various help options. The ones with an asterisk next to them means that your version of BASH doesn't have that builtin command enabled.

In the end, you might have to find an alternative to this built in...

Try this:

```
if echo "$ip" |  egrep -q "^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$"
```

Note that you don't use square or double square brackets at all.

The `-q` option ensures that the `egrep` command won't print out anything. Instead, if the pattern matches, it will return a 0, and if not, it will return a 1. This will work with the `if` command. This is the way we use to do it back in the days of straight Bourne shell where regular expressions weren't built into the shell, and we had to hew shell scripts out of stone, and had real VT100 terminals.

By the way, in your regular expression, `500.600.700.900` will still show up as a valid IP address.

Comment: Or maybe, somehow, you are not using the expected shell... not your command line shell that supports '[['; A weaker shell without a [[ built in will try to find a [[ executable.

Comment: @Gilbert This could be true, but the OP has `#! /bin/bash` in the first line of his program which should specify the `bash` shell. I've seen bash shells linked to `/bin/sh` and if you execute the shell as `/bin/sh`, it won't do bash extensions. I also thought maybe the OP's site has something in `/etc/bashrc` that would eliminate bash additions like `[[`, but I couldn't find any option in either `set -o` or `shopt` that would turn that specific feature on or off. Besides, why would you do that if the user explicitly specified `bash` as their execution shell of choice?

Comment: By this time in my life I have seen all sorts of bizarre thins done with redirecting shells by cp or ln. Not often, but the pain is large when it happens.